# What is the ratio of mixing two liquids

Tags: ratio

Here is my attempted solution

$T1/4$ and there is 3 cups of which would equal $3/4$.

So since there is 3 times more than the ratio would be 3:1. Iis this correct?

Comment: Please proofread your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

That's the ratio of root beer to ice cream. The ratio of ice cream to root beer is 1:3.  1 cup ice cream, 3 cups root beer.